# Bitbucket Pipelines config issue

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

After adding anchors to my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file I got:

CONFIGURATION ERROR
The 'master' section in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml file is missing a 'step'. Please add the missing 'step' to fix the error.

But, according to https://bitbucket-pipelines.prod.public.atl-paas.net/validator, the config is VALID

```
image: node:latest
definitions:
  caches:
    node: ./node_modules
  steps:
    - step: &Test-step
        name: Run tests
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run test
    - step: &Deploy-step
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - sh bin/pipeline/backend-url-replace.sh
          - npm run build
          - sh bin/pipeline/deployment.sh
    - step: &E2E-step
        name: E2E tests
        caches:
          - node
        image: cypress/base:10
        script:
          - set +e; npm run cy:test
          - sh bin/pipeline/cypress-media-cp.sh
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *Test-step
      - step:
        <<: *Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to Test
        deployment: test
      - step:
        <<: *Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to Staging
        trigger: manual
        deployment: staging
    release/*:
      - step: *Test-step
      - step:
        <<: *Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to Staging
        deployment: staging
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sometimes seems to happen due to indentation issues.

You might need to increase the indentation of your lists under each `step` to four spaces (currently it's two):

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *Test-step
      - step:
          <<: *Deploy-step
          name: Deploy to Test
          deployment: test
      - step:
          <<: *Deploy-step
          name: Deploy to Staging
          trigger: manual
          deployment: staging
    release/*:
      - step: *Test-step
      - step:
          <<: *Deploy-step
          name: Deploy to Staging
          deployment: staging
```

Comment: No problem! I'm not sure why their validator doesn't pick up on this, but I've seen it a few times.

Answer (score 1):

@AndroidNoobie solves your problem, but doens't explain what is happening.

In your definitions you indent the mapping that is the value for `step`:

```
- step: &Deploy-step
    caches:
      - node
    script:
      - sh bin/pipeline/backend-url-replace.sh
      - npm run build
      - sh bin/pipeline/deployment.sh
```

i.e. the keys `caches` and `script` are further indented than `step`, this is independent of the anchor being there or not. So that is a sequence element that is mapping with a single key `step`.

If you would write:

```
- step: 
  caches:
    - node
  script:
    - sh bin/pipeline/backend-url-replace.sh
    - npm run build
    - sh bin/pipeline/deployment.sh
```

which is valid YAML, your sequence element is again a mapping but now it has three keys `step`, `caches` and `script`. The value for `step` is `null` (there could be an anchor there, that makes no difference).

And this is what you have in your `pipelines` section. Your merge key `<<` is not the first key in the mapping (and it doesn't have to be).

That makes e.g. the very last element in your example a mapping with five values, instead of a mapping with one key `rest`, and a value for that key that is a mapping with four keys, which is what you need.